# Recorrer List DTO en C#

Tags: c#, lista, foreach

Tengo el siguiente código en c#:

```
List<Usuario> ret = new List<Usuario>();
UsuarioRepositorio repositorio = new UsuarioRepositorio(); 
var dtos = repositorio.Seleccionar(); 
foreach(dtos) 
{ 

    ret.Add(dtos); 
} 

return ret;
```

Como pueden ver, tengo un List llamado `ret` y dtos es un List DTO que recibe los valores del método `Seleccionar()`. Pero me gustaría saber de qué manera recorrer o mapear dtos para almacenarlo en ret, para luego retornarlo.

Comment: A que te refieres cuando dices  *'recorrer o mapear dtos para almacenarlo en ret, para luego retornarlo'*? Puedes dar un ejemplo de guia de lo que quieres?

Comment: No declaras bien el foreach, fíjate en las respuestas que te han dado el resto de usuarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres mapear las propiedades de un dto a un usuario y luego añadirlo a tu lista de usuarios:

```
foreach(var dto in dtos)
{
    //Creo el usuario que vamos a añadir en ret
    Usuario user = new Usuario();

    //Meto las propiedades del dto recorrido en el usuario
    user.propiedad1 = dto.propiedad1;
    user.propiedad2 = dto.propiedad2;
    ....

    //Añado el usuario
    ret.Add(user);
}

return ret;
```

Answer (score 1):

usando System.Collections.Generic

```
List<Usuario> resultado = new List<Usuario>();
dtos.ForEach(dto => {
    var r = new Usuario();
    r.Nombre = dto.Nombre;
    resultado.Add(r);
});
```

aunque si solo es para mapear te recomiendo mirar [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

Saludos,

Answer (score 1):

Muchas gracias a todos, fue de mucha ayuda sus comentarios, ya esta resuelto:

```
public List<Usuario> Seleccionar()
{
     List<Usuario> ret = new List<Usuario>();
     UsuarioRepositorio repositorio = new UsuarioRepositorio();
     var dtos = repositorio.Seleccionar();
     foreach (var dto in dtos)
     {
         ret.Add(UsuarioAdaptador.ConvertirAEntidad(dto));
     }
     return ret;                        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que poner en el `foreach` es un elemento que manejar durante la iteración.

```
foreach(var dato in dtos) // Por cada "dato" en la lista de datos "dtos".
{
    ret.Add(dato);
}
```

Para el caso, cada vez que el `foreach` encuentre un elemento en `dtos` va a "seleccionar" ese elemento y lo va a referenciar en la `var`iable "dato" y así lo tratará dentro de ese bloque.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Usuario> ret = new List<Usuario>();
UsuarioRepositorio repositorio = new UsuarioRepositorio(); 
var dtos = repositorio.Seleccionar(); 


return dtos.ToList();
```